# What happens at/after "Java Expiration Date"?

Tags: java

From this question [JRE Expiration Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16067829/jre-expiration-date/16090237), it was understood that the date refers to "the date by which Java will consider itself out of date".

The [release highlights](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/release_changes.xml) also mention about it:

> Java Expiration Date
>
> The expiration date for 8u66 is January 19, 2016. Java expires whenever a new release with security vulnerability fixes becomes available. For systems unable to reach the Oracle Servers, a secondary mechanism expires this JRE (version 8u66) on February 19, 2016. After either condition is met (new release becoming available or expiration date reached), Java will provide additional warnings and reminders to users to update to the newer version.

However, I was not able to find any source (official Oracle would be good) mentioning more details about what would happen at/after the "Java Expiration Date".

- Does it affects desktop or server use of Java?
- In a server application, would the application stop running?
- Can the warning be turned off by some settings?

---

Update:

Found in Java Platform, Standard Edition Deployment Guide [23.1.2 JRE Expiration Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/client-security.html#BGBCCDHD), 23.1.2.2, point 4. Seem that the expiry date affects RIA.

Comment: Update: Found the following info, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/client-security.html

Answer (score 3):

It affects both server and private use of Java. A server application will not suddenly stop working.

It simply means that Oracle will not provide support and updates for this particular major version anymore:

> Java SE 7 End of Public Updates Notice After April 2015, Oracle will
>   no longer post updates of Java SE 7 to its public download sites.
>   Existing Java SE 7 downloads already posted as of April 2015 will
>   remain accessible in the Java Archive on Oracle Technology Network.
>   Developers and end-users are encouraged to update to more recent Java
>   SE versions that remain available for public download.
>
> Long Term Support Customers who need continued access to critical bug
>   fixes and security fixes as well as general maintenance for Java SE 7
>   or older versions can get long term support through Oracle Java SE
>   Support.

From: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html, also mentioned in the question you linked.

Comment: I'm more referring to this:

"Java Expiration Date
The expiration date for 8u66 is January 19, 2016. Java expires whenever a new release with security vulnerability fixes becomes available. For systems unable to reach the Oracle Servers, a secondary mechanism expires this JRE (version 8u66) on February 19, 2016. After either condition is met (new release becoming available or expiration date reached), Java will provide additional warnings and reminders to users to update to the newer version."

Not support of major version. Each update has an expiration date.